# async lambda expression with arguments

Tags: c#, async-await

I am trying to call my async function from a wrapper. But I am getting this compiler error. In the following code, I would like to get `string x` value with most of awaits abstracted/pushed into `CallAsyncFunc` code. What is the right way to do this in c# 4.5? Thanks!

> error CS4010: Cannot convert async lambda expression to delegate type
>    '`System.Func<int,string>`'. An async lambda expression may return `void`,
>    `Task` or `Task<T>`, none of which are convertible to
>    '`System.Func<int,string>`'.

```
public async Task<T2> CallAsyncFunc<T1,T2>(T1 a, Func<T1, T2> func)
{
    return func.Invoke(a);
}

public async Task<string> GetString(int value)
{
    await Task.Run(() => Thread.Sleep(2000));
    return "" + value;
}

public async Task MainAsyncEntry()
{
    string x = await CallAsyncFunc<int, string>(30, async(x) => await GetString(x));
}
```

Comment: C# isn't JavaScript. `"" + value` should be `value.ToString()`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In:

```
string x = await CallAsyncFunc<int, string>(30, async(x) => await GetString(x));
```

You have two `x` that the first issue. Try:

```
string y = await CallAsyncFunc<int, string>(30, async(x) => await GetString(x));
```

Here the output of the lambda is `string` but because you use `async` it should be a `Task` or `Task<T>`.

You can write:

```
string y = await CallAsyncFunc<int, string>(30, x => GetString(x).Result);
// Equivalent to
string y = await CallAsyncFunc(30, x => GetString(x).Result);
```

Or

```
string y = await CallAsyncFunc<int, Task<string>>(30, x => GetString(x)).Result;
// Equivalent to
string y = await CallAsyncFunc(30, GetString).Result;
```

But in either cases, your `CallAsyncFunc` will run synchronously because it did not contain any `await`.

Here the good way to do it:

```
// This
public async Task<TOut> CallAsyncFunc<TIn, TOut>(TIn input, Func<TIn, Task<TOut>> func)
{
    return await func.Invoke(input);
}

// Or those
public Task<TOut> CallAsyncFunc<TIn, TOut>(TIn input, Func<TIn, Task<TOut>> func)
{
    return func.Invoke(input);
}

public async Task<string> GetString(int value)
{
    await Task.Run(() => Thread.Sleep(2000));
    return value.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
}

public async Task MainAsyncEntry()
{
    string y = await CallAsyncFunc(30, GetString);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Remark 1: 
`await GetString(x)` unwraps the `Task<string>` to `string`, then `CallAsyncFunc` wraps again into `Task<string>`. **You should rather keep the wrapped expression all the way long of your calling stack.** It is the recommanded way as far as I know.

Remark 2: 
Resharper warns about CallAsyncFunc:

> This async method lacks ‘ await’  operators and will run synchronously. Consider using the ‘await’ operator to await non-blocking API calls, or ‘ await TaskEx.Run(…)’ to do CPU-bound work on a background thread

Indeed you can ommit the `async`keyword and avoid the re-wrapping into `Task<string>`.

As a result of Remark 1 and Remark 2, you could write following colde:

```
// REALLY ASYNC METHOD, WRAPS THE RESULT INTO Task<string>
public async Task<string> GetString(int value)
{
    await Task.Run(() => Thread.Sleep(2000));
    return "" + value;
}

// NOT ASYNC ANY MORE: DOES NOT WRAP THE RESULT INTO Task<T2> any more
public T2 CallAsyncFunc<T1, T2>(T1 a, Func<T1, T2> func)
{
    return func.Invoke(a);
}

// WAIT FOR THE ASYNC RESULT ONLY IN THE OUTER SCOPE (UNWRAPS Task<string> BY THE WAY)
string y = await CallAsyncFunc(30, GetString);
string z = await CallAsyncFunc<int, Task<string>>(30, GetString);
```

Comment: Great! That works. Is there anyway to reduce one await to get final value? Currently, it is 'string yval = await await CallAsyncFunc(..)'